# @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises with const function declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm having trouble understanding why the `@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises` works with some, but not all my async functions.

In my understanding, the following 2 functions are equivalent

```js
const getUser = async (userId: string): Promise<User> => {
  const userRef = await getUsersCollection().doc(userId).get()
  return userRef.data()
}

async function getUser2(userId: string) {
  const userRef = await getUsersCollection().doc(userId).get()
  return userRef.data()
}
```

How ever when I run `npm lint` (or look at my code in VS Code) only one call triggers the `no floating promises` error - why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't assign the result of the promise to anything.

Either assign it

```
const x = getUser2()
```

or handle it

```
getUser2().then(() => do something).catch(() => do something else)
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of `no-floating-promise` to warn you of any awaitable functions that are neither awaited nor using then/catch()?

Comment: Yes, every async function returns a promise. So you created a promise, but you didn't handle it. Where do you use `user` later?

Comment: It's just used inside an if() where I check null-ness which is why I didn't realize that that `user` is of type Promise. I still believe that if a variable does not leave the function scope (being returned or passed to another function) the rule could trigger. Maybe I'm missing an edge case?